# How to connect to an Oracle database with JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, driver, datasource

I currently have a connection for MySQL database and connected as:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://${mysql.service.host}:${mysql.service.port}/${mysql.service.database}
```

If I were to change the database and used Oracle database instead then how would the datasource URL change?

Comment: I highly recommend that you consult the [Oracle JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-C4F2CA86-0F68-400C-95DA-30171C9FB8F0) for the format of Oracle JDBC URLs.

Answer (score 2):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:port/service
```

or

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:port:SID
```

The server entry would be the IP address or network name where your Oracle Listener is handling connection requests. The port would be the port number being used for said listener requests.

Service would be the database service name, if you're connecting to an Oracle Pluggable Database, you'll always need this.

The SID is a unique ID for your database, you could use that, but you're encouraged to use the service instead.

If you wish to make a THICK connection, that is, use an Oracle Client to make a connection to your database, then things get a bit more complicated. I would suggest using THIN until you can't.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!